# How do I make a curve that goes through a series of points?

Tags: bezier-curves

This seems simple (to Adobe Illustrator users maybe?) but how do I get a 2D curve to go through say 12 points. Such that each bezier handle is determined by the previous and next point in the row? "Path" in photoshop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can "draw" connected points by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and the right mouse button. The bézier hadles will be calculated automatically.

[image]

Or you can use the grease pencil to draw and convert the strokes to curves.

Curve editing in blender is still quite rudimentary, for complex shapes it is a lot easier to use a vector drawing program (like inkscape, illustrator, etc), save the path as SVG and import into blender.